# typo3 Resize image with image adjustment

Tags: typo3-6.2.x

When I change the `Image adjustment` width in the backend, the frontend image keeps the default width.

How to enable this option?

Using typo3 v6.2.4 - Bootstrap package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this article](http://typo3.org/news/article/responsive-image-rendering-in-typo3-cms-62/) selecting `Default img-tag` in `Rendering-type for responsive images` constant should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

TYPO3 by default max width is 600px, thing you need to do is overwrite in TypoScript: setup.ts

```
tt_content.image.20.maxW = 1920
tt_content.image.20.maxWInText = 1920
```

This may be useful for other people!
Cheers!